# What is role of 2nd parameter & 3rd parameter in fwrite()? Why we need 3rcount here? 

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fwrite

Hi fwrite()'s signature is as follows:

```
size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9t88zwz.aspx

**I didnt understand the difference between 2nd parameter "size" & 3rd parameter "count"?**

Does it mean size of the data copied from buffer to file is of size "size". And what role does count has to play here. ??

Comment: Did you read that documentation you link to? Esp. the Remarks section?

Answer (score 3):

you're writing COUNT things, each one of which is of size SIZE.

So if you have an array of 50 FooBar structures, you would do:

```
fwrite( some_pointer, sizeof(FooBar), 50, some_stream );
```

So you *could* always set size to 1, and instead write:

```
fwrite( some_pointer, 1, 50 * sizeof(FooBar), some_stream);
```

but I believe the first way is, if nothing else, much easier to read and less error prone.

Comment: I was taught way back when that the first way was more I/O buffer friendly.  Not sure if that holds true anymore though.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you've an array as:

```
T a[N]; //T is the type of each element
        //and N is the number of elements in the array
//fill the array here
```

Now, you want to write this array using `fwrite`, so you pass `a` as first argument as:

```
fwrite(a, ..... );
```

Now how will `fwrite` know how many bytes it needs to write? It cannot know this from its first argument because `a` gets converted into `const void*` which loses lots of useful information, such as the *type* each elements in the array<sup>1</sup>, thereby it could have calculated the size of each element, but this information is lost the moment you pass `a` as first argument. So you need to pass the size of each element as:

```
fwrite(a, sizeof(T), ....);
```

Now `fwrite` knows the address (or pointer) from where it will read the elements, and it also knows the *size* of each element. But it still doesn't know *how many elements*. So you pass the number of elements in the array, as:

```
fwrite(a, sizeof(T), N, ...);
```

And now it knows everything about the data. Now all it needs to know is the file-pointer. So here you write it as:

```
FILE *fp = /*.....*/ ;
fwrite(a, sizeof(T), N, fp);
```

Hope that helps.

---

<sup>1. When `a` converts into `const void*`, it also loses another useful information which is the *number* of elements. But in C, you cannot pass an array as argument. When you do so, it will decay into pointer, losing the information about the size of the array. `fwrite` is a function from C library. However, if you're using `fwrite` in C++, then you can wrap it in a function template as:</sup>

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t fwrite(T (&a)[N], FILE *fp)
{
   return fwrite(a, sizeof(T), N, fp); //call the C function here
}
```

Then you can simply call it as:

```
int a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
double b={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};

fwrite(a,fp); 
fwrite(b,fp);
```

Looks good? But you cannot pass a pointer to this:

```
float *c = new float[100];

fwrite(c,fp); //compilation error
```

It is because our `fwrite` function template will accept only array, not pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Size is the size of each element you want to write. If it's bytes you should use `1`, otherwise use `sizeof(whatever)`.

Count is the number of those elements you want to write.